# Image.network not displaying Image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

All of the values from the response are showing except for the image.
One weird thing is that when I try to build it from my laptop, the images show. but when I try to build it on my PC, it doesn't.

No errors found in debug.

here is the sample of the response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "user_id": 1,
    "caption": "Ambot ya",
    "image": "storage\/images\/posts\/image\/20190927UTC163833894.jpeg",
    "type": "image",
    "created_at": "2019-09-27 16:38:33",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-27 16:38:33",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "likes_count": 1,
    "isLiked": 0,
    "comments": [],
    "likes": [
```

here is how I get the response;

```
  Future<List<Feed>> getFeedAll() async {
    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(APIServices.HTTP_DOMAIN + APIServices.POST_GET_ALL),
        headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + Constants.token});
    print(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);

      print(data);

      feedList = data.map<Feed>((json) => Feed.fromJson(json)).toList();
      print(feedList);
    }
    print("List Size: ${feedList.length}");

    return feedList;
  }
```

and here is how I display it:

```
Image.network("${APIServices.HTTP_DOMAIN}${feed[index].image}",
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          )
```

**EDIT**:
I'm using an actual device to test. SAMSUNG J7 PRO

Comment: Can you print value of `"${APIServices.HTTP_DOMAIN}${feed[index].image}"` and try launching that URL in browser. Why are you adding `.image` extension to `.jpeg`? Its not required (if server is already sending it)

Comment: I've printed the value of `"${APIServices.HTTP_DOMAIN}${feed[index].image}"` and it shows the image in the browser. `.image` is a string variable from my Feed object

Comment: My mistake. You said it works on your laptop, didn't observer that either.

Answer (score 0):

first check [flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web-images)
then if that 2-ways cant solve your issue use this widget

```dart
 if (kIsWeb) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              width: 450,
              child: Image.asset('Assets/Images/placeHolder.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 450,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(imageUrl ?? ""), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30403694)